# proof of infimum and upper bound of $(1+1/n)^n$

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

I have to prove that 2 is the minimum, and therefore infimum of the set of all numbers $(1+1/n)^n$, where $n$ are positive integer numbers. And also that it is upper bounded, not necessarily to show that its supremum is $e$.

I'm having difficulties finding a way to prove the second statement. I've tried using an inequality in the sense that the definition of the set is less than an arbitrary number like 3, but I've run on dead ends. The first one I somehow proved it, by trying to show that the terms of the set are always increasing as $n$ does, and therefore, for $n=1$ the smallest term is obtained (which is 2). Still, its quite messy and I'm sure there must be cleaner ways to solve this.

I still want to solve the exercise, could I get any small hint on what to do to go the right way?

Comment: For lower bound Bernoulli inequality: $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$ if (1+x)>0. Hence you immediately get a lower bound of 2.

Comment: Far easier than solution in answer posted: $(1+1/n)^n \le (1+1/n)^{n+1}$ and the RHS is decreasing (take derivative and check) so is bounded above so the LHS is bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a logically sound proof that an upper bound must exist although it might be a bit above what you are currently studying depending on what you have previously proved (specifically about integrals, derivatives, and L'Hopital's rule).

---

Define

$$f(x)=\int_{1}^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

$1)$ For any $r>0$ we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x^r)=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d}{du}f(u)$$

where $u=x^r$. Then

$$=rx^{r-1}\frac{1}{u}=\frac{rx^{r-1}}{x^r}=\frac{r}{x}$$

In a similar manner, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} rf(x)=\frac{r}{x}$$

Since the derivatives are equal, we may conclude

$$f(x^r)=rf(x)+C$$

for some constant $C$. To find this, note that at $x=1$ we have

$$f(1)=\int_1^1\frac{1}{t}dt=0$$

Thus

$$0=f(1)=f(1^r)=rf(1)+C=C$$

We conclude that for all $r>0$ we have $f(x^r)=rf(x)$.

$2)$ Consider

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(1+x)}{x}$$

Using L'Hopital's rule this is

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1+x}=1$$

$3)$ Finally, we have

$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Using the limit proved in $2)$ this is equal to

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}nf\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]$$

Additionally, note that

$$f(4)=\int_1^4 \frac{1}{t}dt>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{13}{12}>1$$

and that

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}>0$$

These statements are enough to conclude that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is eventually bounded above by $4$ since otherwise we would have that

$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]\geq f(4)\geq \frac{13}{12}$$

for an infinite number of $n$. Thus, there is some $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<4$$

We conclude that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<\max\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k+5:1\leq k\leq N\right\}$$